# .htaccess - redirect if no subdomain and pass the wrong subdomain name to another page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I want to make the a redirect on .htaccess if someone put a wrong subdomain (that doesn't exist) and pass this subdomain phraze to the another page:

BAD SUBDOMAIN:

```
ABC.example.org
```

REDIRECTION:

```
my-page.com?validate=ABC
```

How can I do this?

Comment: ¿Do you mean: If someone writes a wrong URL with a subdomain that does not exist, you want to map that 404 error to the address http://.., or is it in your site anybody can really add subdomains? If it is the last option, that can't be corrected with some rules in .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Your subdomain must be resolved by a DNS server and if it is wrong(that doesn't exists) the browser will display error that can't find server. So, browser can't connect your server and how can .htaccess file work?